# Blocking Session Storage

Tags: php, ajax, session, websocket

We make usage of Guzzle HTTP in order to make HTTP(s) request in order to generate a CSV file; Another component that we use is the `$_SESSION` variable to store status information about the generation of the different files.

The main problem with this approach is that PHP blocks all other requests that make usage of the `$_SESSION` variable. We know that we can defeat this "problem" with a certain function that is called `session_write_close()`;

But we still need to be able to update the information and store it in the `$_SESSION` variable later on and we should also be able to use the `$_SESSION` information in other sections of the site; Thus it should be "synced".

Comment: You can always start the session again later in the script, write to it, and close it again. This will reduce blocking considerably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP sessions are implemented on the assumption that session data is:

1. Loaded in its entirety from the backing store.
2. Possibly modified during the execution of a script.
3. Written in its entirety to its backing store.

So, for example, let's say that you implement a session handler that does not implement locking and the following sequence of events takes place.

1. Request A loads session data from the backing store.
2. Request B loads session data from the backing store.
3. Request A modifies $_SESSION['foo']
4. Request B is busy doing stuff...
5. Request A completes and writes the session to the backing store.
6. Request B completes and writes the session to the backing store, obliterating changes made by A.

This is why PHP's default session handler, and any other session handler worth its salt, locks each session for the duration of a given request.

Given that you need to write data at the end of a long-running request and also have multiple running in parallel you should probably not be using sessions at all for this data, and I would suggest using a database *and* transactions.

Comment: Probably this is the best solution for our problem, the only problem is that we should make no usage of a database whatsoever. Thus we'll be reevaluating our options. Currently we close and reopen our $_SESSION "connections" each time required, but this is quite wonky.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly `session_write_close` is exactly what you would need to use in order to make sure the request is not blocking. My suggestion is to get and set all the session information you need at the start of the script, before you start to generate your CSV. Then call `session_write_close` and continue with creating your CSV file.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that we need to update the status of the CSV generation later on in the script.

Comment: If you need to update it in the session data then yes. You have to decide which of the two consequences is the lesser evil.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you is that your request is taking much longer than typical request. The reason is time needed to do HTTP requests from your script(s). This causes your initial issue with blocking session file.

I can see two solutions to your problem:

1. Offload your logic related to making requests into different process that is passed all the info needed without actual session usage (worker). This can be achieved by using queues or even simple cron script that peeks up what it needs to do from some shared storage, like DB.
2. Give up on using Sessions or at least on using blocking storage for sessions. Good alternatives may be: simple DB table with info required, key-value storages like memcached or Redis.